# Can I still download OS X Mavericks for Free?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I never upgraded to Mountain Lion or Mavericks and now that Yosemite has arrived  I thought of upgrading but I find that some of my software will not work with it. So I would like to upgrade to Mavericks for now. Is it still possible to get the free upgrade? I no longer see it listed in the Mac App Store.

Comment: You will need a full version of Mavericks that is a 5.3 Gig file. Do not get fulled with files that are less than that in size.

Comment: I tried going through Apple Support but struck out-
“Ah, okay. I'd like to start with letting you know there is only one way to download mavericks now. You would need an Apple ID that has been used to install mavericks before. Then you can sign into the App store, and mavericks will show under the "Purchases" section.”

There is the possibility if you know someone with an Apple ID that had Mavericks before, you can log in with that and access it from the App Store. Otherwise, you might be able to buy a used Mac that had/has it and then use the Recovery Partition to install to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is still possible to download Mavericks: http://www.techspot.com/downloads/6268-mac-os-x-mavericks.html

That is a upgrade from Mavericks 10.9.4 to 10.9.5 (not a full version of Mavericks which is a 5.3 Gig file.)

But maybe the software not working on Yosemite may neither works on Mavericks.

Comment: That link is a Upgrade from 10.9.4 to 10.9.5 only. The full Mavericks is 5.3 Gig file.

Comment: Yeah, true. I didn't found the full Mavericks, except on private torrent :(

Comment: The Techspot download appears to be a gimmick. I tried to download it, but was taken to a page to download Zip7 (or some zip software).